# Auto hide heading in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am writing a HTML code

```
echo "<html>
<body>
<style>
h3 {color:green}
</style>
<h3>Mail Sent Successfully</h3>
</body>
</html>";
```

here I want message to disappear after 5 seconds, is there any way to make this happen

Comment: JS / Jquery, should do it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/bwqo2L43/

Comment: Sidenote: avoid echo'ing html from PHP. Some template engine (like SMARTY http://www.smarty.net/ would come in handy)

Answer (score 3):

a little javascript should do it.

```
    window.onload=function(){
        setTimeout( function(){
            document.querySelectorAll('h3')[0].innerHTML='';
        },5000);
    }
```

Comment: Giving `id` to element would be more specific and efficient!

Comment: Probably true but the html is so lightweight I don't think you'd notice any significant speed improvements